# Redis not able to connect using redis-rb (with Redistogo URL)

Tags: ruby, redis

I've created a Redis To Go Nano plan on Heroku and I'm using the connection URL in different
Heroku applications to share a rate-limit counter. Following all usual steps this is what I did.

I've added the add-on and I got back the REDISTOGO_URL.

```
# redis url
redis://user:pass@spadefish.redistogo.com:9014/
```

This is the raised error.

```
RuntimeError: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I tried to simulate the connection from command line.

```
store = Redis.connect(url: 'redis://user:pass@spadefish.redistogo.com:9014/')
```

store.get('key') # raises error

And I get that error. If I use the local Redis instance everything works just fine.

```
store = Redis.connect(url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0')
store('key') # does not raise error
```

Everything makes me think it's a problem related to the Redis URL.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue that occurred with the redis to go spadefish server.
A CNAME was not initially configured for spadefish so you were getting a DNS resolution  error.
The CNAME for spadefish has been added and you should not have a problem connecting to your instance.